# Replacing Strings Java

Tags: java, string, replace, buffer, lowercase

I have this function to check if some words appear in a specific line, and then surround them with a given char.

The code above works like a charm, however since the words in the string array "words" are always low case, the words will be lower case as well. How can i fix this issue ?

The inputs:

```
BufferedReader in = "Hello, my name is John:";
char c = '*';
String [] words = {"hello","john"};
```

The desired output:

```
BufferedWriter out = "*Hello*, my name is *John*:";
```

The actual output:

```
BufferedWriter out = "*hello*, my name is *john*";
```

The code:

```
public void replaceString(BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out, char c, String[] words){

String line_in = in.readLine();

    while (line_in != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

            line_in = line_in.replaceAll("(?i)" + words[j], bold + words[j]
                    + bold);

        }

        out.write(line_in);
        out.newLine();
        line_in = in.readLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
line_in.replaceAll("(?i)(" + words[j] + ")", bold + "$1" + bold);
//                      \________________/           \/
//                         capture word          reference it
```